# parsley.js with jquery-chosen errorsClass not applied

Tags: jquery-chosen, parsley.js

I'm struggling to work out why parsley.js won't add the errorClass I've defined to fields enhanced with chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damiantaylor/64wps0bt/2/) which shows the issue I have. There are 2 identical select lists - one enhanced with chosen and the other standard.

When you click the submit button, both fields are validated but only the standard select has the 'has-error' class applied to its parent 'input-group' div.

Any ideas? I'd like to get these two great plugins playing together.

Code follows:

```
<form id="myForm">
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="select" name="a[]" multiple="multiple" data-parsley-required data-parsley-mincheck="2">
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <select name="b[]" multiple="multiple" data-parsley-required data-parsley-mincheck="2">
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Section">
            <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
            <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ParsleyConfig = {
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        successClass: 'has-success',
        classHandler: function(ParsleyField) {
            return ParsleyField.$element.parents('.input-group');
        },
        errorsContainer: function(ParsleyField) {
            return ParsleyField.$element.parents('.input-group');
        },
        errorsWrapper: '<span class="error-block">',
        errorTemplate: '<div></div>'
    };

    $(".select").chosen();

    $("#myForm").parsley();

    $("#myForm").on('submit', function(e) {
        var f = $(this);
        f.parsley().validate();

        if (f.parsley().isValid()) {
            alert('The form is valid');
        } else {
            alert('There are validation errors');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

.has-error {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the solution was simple!

The change is to the return from classHandler and errorsContainer - use parent (singular) instead of parents (plural)

change the config js to....

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
    errorClass: 'has-error',
    successClass: 'has-success',
    classHandler: function(ParsleyField) {
        return ParsleyField.$element.parent('.input-group');
    },
    errorsContainer: function(ParsleyField) {
        return ParsleyField.$element.parent('.input-group');
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<span class="error-block">',
    errorTemplate: '<div></div>'
};
```